# Is there a specific word or name that refers to someone who studies a lot but is not intelligent

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, slang

I have heard this word in other languages. It refers (in the bad sense) to those persons who are really hard working, study a lot, memorize, but in fact do not have the intelligence knack. They are not wise, but hardworking.

Comment: I think the closest English has is "*book smart*", but that implies naïveté, not a lack of intelligence (in other words, book smart people *are* smart, just not wise).

Comment: What's the word in other languages?

Comment: I had thought that the word might be "a swot" (at least in certain dialects);  to me it has a negative connotation of someone who works hard but lacks actual aptitude.  But the OED entry does not seem to confirm this negative connotation.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "cow"

Comment: @WolfgangKuehne How udderly ridiculous.

Comment: I'm somewhat inclined to think that while there may be a word that partially approximates the idea, that the concept itself is not really one that is part of the stock of American stereotypes. We tend to assume that hard workers who study a lot are also generally fairly intelligent.

Comment: A "plug 'n chugger" is an engineering student who can only solve problems that are presented in a form that drops straight in to a formula. It is definitely a disparaging term. But someone who manages to get by with hard work is not often disparaged. There's also *cookbook chemistry* (which seems to have been embraced https://www.amazon.com/Organic-Chemistry-Cookbook-Original-Study/dp/1453813454 ).

Answer (score 4):

Such a person might be called a *[grind](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grind)*:-

> *Informal* A student who works or studies excessively.
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary via The Free Dictionary].

This doesn't invariably mean someone not particularly bright, but it carries that implication (they are *grinding* facts into their head, mechanically and without inspiration).

Answer (score 1):

"Book Smart" ~ having a lot of academic knowledge learned from books and studying, but not necessarily knowing much about people and living in the real world

Answer (score 0):

You might mean "Dweeb".

[image]

Know about it [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dweeb).

Comment: Dweeb refers more to lack of social skills than lack of intelligence or presence of diligence.