# word descibes teaching by order

Tags: meaning, verbs, adjectives, adverbs

What is the proper word for describing the kind of teaching which based on executing/applying what you heard from your teacher without thinking of it or even applying reason. To just to do what you have heard.

Comment: The usual 'BrE' expression for blithely echoing what you have been taught  is 'repeating [something] parrot-fashion'. From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/parrot-fashion): adverb British

Without thought or understanding; mechanically:
*she repeated the phrase parrot-fashion*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Derogatory word, describing person (a pupil) who memorizes instead of learning?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313712/derogatory-word-describing-person-a-pupil-who-memorizes-instead-of-learning)

Comment: Indoctrination isn't quite right, but the question implies something more drastic than just memorization.

Comment: Not a dupe of that question. OP is not asking for a derogatory term, nor a term for the pupil. The request is for a term for a kind of teaching.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called **learning by rote**. A kind of learning style that isn't really learning but repeating exactly as you were told. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rote_learning.

Comment: what about the word "didactic", is it right as well?

Comment: @Elpharaoh Didactic just means "to teach" as in _didactic methodology._ Possibly you are thinking of pedantic, but that doesn't really work either.

Answer (score 0):

***Memorization***

is also a term you could use for what you describe.

[Dictionary.com defines it as follows](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/memorization):

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/memorization

> verb (used with object), memorized, memorizing.
>   to commit to memory; learn by heart:
>   *to memorize a poem.*
>
> verb (used without object), memorized, memorizing.
>   to learn by heart:
>   *I've always been able to memorize easily.*